# Conditional Formatting based on value of another sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I am using below formula that is working fine on same sheet to highlight the row where found "Terminated".

=$E3="Terminate"

I want to highlight the same row on other sheets as well where found "Terminate" on "Leave Data" sheet range E3.

*Each sheet has same Employees name on Col B. May that would made it easy to highlight the same row on other sheets*

Can someone please share a solution to this question.

Comment: Can you share some screenshots, sample data or a link to an example sheet?

Comment: Sure here is the sheet link. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZCrQlBjfMmO9636npMth9ErDr4kSnK8LhKb7JXS2KxU/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conditional formatting does not support direct sheet references, but you can "trick" it by using `INDIRECT` and `CELL`:

So in cell A1 of Sheet3, create a conditional formatting rule valid for the whole range `A1:A100` and insert this formula:

```
=INDIRECT("Sheet2!"&CELL("address", E1))="Terminate"
```

- [INDIRECT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377?hl=en)
- [CELL](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3267071?hl=en)

#### Explanation

Between INDIRECT and CELL, it creates an "indirect" reference to the value of the target cell which conditional formatting can understand.

You can also make it fill the whole row by adding a `$` to the `E` as in this formula:

```
=INDIRECT("Sheet2!"&CELL("address", $E1))="Terminate"
```